# "rmmod g_hid" causes kernel crash: "Device 'hidg.0' does not have a release() function, it is broken and must be fixed"

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, hid

I am getting the below kernel crash when I try to `rmmod` the `g_hid` module. Can someone provide me with a lead?

```
[  261.125986] ------------[ cut here ]------------  
[  261.130656] Device 'hidg.0' does not have a release() function, it is broken and must be fixed. See Documentation/kobject.txt.  
[  261.142142] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 938 at drivers/base/core.c:1103 device_release+0x70/0x80  
[  261.150321] Modules linked in: usb_f_hid g_hid(-) qca9377(O) crct10dif_ce phy_generic ci_hdrc_imx ci_hdrc usbmisc_imx  
[  261.160944] CPU: 2 PID: 938 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G           O      5.4.70-2.3.0+g5f2220e87dd8 #1  
[  261.169812] Hardware name: FSL i.MX8MM EVK board (DT)  
[  261.174863] pstate: 40000005 (nZcv daif -PAN -UAO)  
[  261.179655] pc : device_release+0x70/0x80  
[  261.183667] lr : device_release+0x70/0x80  
[  261.187674] sp : ffff8000120cbd50  
[  261.190986] x29: ffff8000120cbd50 x28: ffff0000716a7000  
[  261.196297] x27: 0000000000000000 x26: 0000000000000000  
[  261.201608] x25: 0000000056000000 x24: 0000000000000015  
[  261.206919] x23: ffff800011a55fd0 x22: ffff000072c55080  
[  261.212229] x21: 0000000000000000 x20: ffff000072f85600  
[  261.217540] x19: ffff8000090ec158 x18: 0000000000000010  
[  261.222851] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000  
[  261.228162] x15: ffff0000716a7470 x14: 6562207473756d20  
[  261.233472] x13: 646e61206e656b6f x12: 7262207369207469  
[  261.238783] x11: 202c6e6f6974636e x10: 7566202928657361  
[  261.244094] x9 : 656c657220612065 x8 : ffff800011ba9000  
[  261.249405] x7 : ffff8000106a1a28 x6 : 0000000000000544  
[  261.254716] x5 : 0000000000000000 x4 : ffff00007dba8188  
[  261.260027] x3 : ffff00007dbaef20 x2 : ffff00007dba8188  
[  261.265337] x1 : 01430cd05f3e4f00 x0 : 0000000000000000  
[  261.270648] Call trace:  
[  261.273094]  device_release+0x70/0x80  
[  261.276757]  kobject_put+0x74/0xf0  
[  261.280158]  put_device+0x10/0x20  
[  261.283474]  platform_device_unregister+0x28/0x38  
[  261.288182]  hidg_cleanup+0x2c/0xb6c [g_hid]  
[  261.292454]  __arm64_sys_delete_module+0x140/0x228  
[  261.297246]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x68/0x160  
[  261.302036]  el0_svc_handler+0x20/0x80  
[  261.305785]  el0_svc+0x8/0x208  
[  261.308837] ---[ end trace 1b878641e3d35ced ]---
```

Comment: Which bit of `Device ... is broken and must be fixed` are you having problems with?  Are you modifying the driver to fix the bug, or are you content to just live with it (i.e. don't `rmmod` the module)?  Those are the two available options.

Comment: @TobySpeight I want to use usb gadget hid keyboard. After use of that module, module must get removed.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to add a working `release()` function to the module and recompile it.  Don't forget to send the patch upstream!